# Element-wise multiplication of two lists in Tcl

Tags: list, tcl, multiplication

I have two lists of same length and I want to multiply them element-wise(like Cartesian product in sets). How do I do it? For example, if I write

```
set a {1 2 3 4 5} 
set b {1 2 3 4 5}
```

,then the desired output is :
    {1 4 9 16 25}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A two-list `lmap` is perfect for this:

```
set a {1 2 3 4 5}
set b {1 2 3 4 5}

set result [lmap x $a y $b {expr {$x * $y}}]
```

If you're on Tcl 8.5 (or older) use this instead:

```
set a {1 2 3 4 5}
set b {1 2 3 4 5}

set result {}
foreach x $a y $b {
    lappend result [expr {$x * $y}]
}
```

The multi-list form of `foreach` has been supported for a very long time indeed.